# On the series $\sum \limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos n}{n^2+1}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Prove that

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos n}{n^2+1} = \frac{\pi \cosh (\pi -1)}{\sinh \pi }$$

I already have a solution using Fourier expansion of the exponential function. I'm interested in a complex analysis approach. It would be natural to consider the function

$$f(z) = \frac{\pi \cot \pi z \cos z}{z^2+1}$$

and integrate it around an appropriate contour $\Gamma_N$ ( say a square ) The residues at $z=i$ and $z=-i$ are equal;

$$\mathfrak{Res}_{z=i} f(z) = \mathfrak{Res}_{z=-i} f(z) = - \frac{\pi \cosh 1 \coth \pi}{2}$$

Thus,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i } \oint \limits_{\Gamma_N} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z = \sum_{n=-N}^{N}  \mathfrak{Res}_{z=n} f(z) + \mathfrak{Res}_{z=i} f(z) + \mathfrak{Res}_{z=-i} f(z)$$

If we let $N \rightarrow +\infty$ the contour would go to $0$ and we would pick the result. However, this is not the case. Something's missing. The main question is why is that? Can you suggest an appropriate kernel function as well as a contour?

Comment: Curiously, inputting this sum into *Mathematica* yields $_2F_1$ with complex arguments, and cannot be boiled down into hyperbolic functions even using `FunctionExpand`. This is one of the few series that can be tackled with simple residue yet intractable to *Mathematica*.

Comment: It can also be tackled using Fourier series ..! Yet I had noticed that Mathematica cannot do the sum !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: try to integrate
$$f(z)=\frac{{\pi {e^{iz}}}}{{({z^2} + 1)({e^{2\pi iz}} - 1)}}$$
around the rectangular contour with vertices $\pm R \pm Ri$, with $R$ a half integer. You might want to check carefully that the integral indeed tends to $0$.

The sum of residues at $z=\pm i$ is $\frac{i}{2}\frac{{\pi \cosh (\pi  - 1)}}{{\sinh \pi }}$, giving
$$ - \frac{i}{2}\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{in}}}}{{{n^2} + 1}}}  + \frac{i}{2}\frac{{\pi \cosh (\pi  - 1)}}{{\sinh \pi }} = 0$$

Comment: Interesting ! What led you consider that function and why is the function I considered not working ?

Comment: @Tolaso  The reason your function doesn't work because $|\cos z|$ is very large when $|\Im(z)|$ is large, so integral around the contour doesn't tends to $0$.

Comment: 10k rep! Congratulations from Hong Kong!

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With the [Poisson's Sumation Formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.8.E14):
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{n} \over
n^{2} + 1}} =
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{t} \over t^{2} + 1}\expo{-2\pi\ic nt}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{\pars{1 - 2n\pi}\ic t} \over t^{2} + 1}\,\dd t +
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{\pars{-1 - 2n\pi}\ic t} \over t^{2} + 1}\,\dd t}
\end{align}

---

However,
$\ds{\left.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{\ic kt} \over t^{2} + 1}\,\dd t\,\right\vert_{\ k\ \in\ \mathbb{R}} = \pi\expo{-\verts{k}}}$.

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{n} \over
n^{2} + 1}} =
{1 \over 2}\,\pi\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\expo{-\verts{2n\pi - 1}} + \expo{-\verts{2n\pi + 1}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\pi\cosh\pars{\pi - 1} \over \sinh\pars{\pi}} \approx 1.1739
\\ &
\end{align}

Comment: How did you sum that last series?