# Evaluate in close form $\sum_{{n}=\mathbf{1}}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\boldsymbol{\eta} \boldsymbol{n})}{\boldsymbol{n}^{2}+\boldsymbol{b}^{2}}$

Tags: summation, fourier-series, fourier-transform, poisson-summation-formula

Let Parameters $\boldsymbol{b} \in \mathbb{R} \backslash\{\boldsymbol{0}\}$ and $\boldsymbol{\eta} \in[\mathbf{0}, \boldsymbol{\pi}] .$
I want to evaluate in close form using hyperbolic functions the sum
$$\sum_{\boldsymbol{n}=\mathbf{1}}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\boldsymbol{\eta} \boldsymbol{n})}{\boldsymbol{n}^{2}+\boldsymbol{b}^{2}}$$
It seems clear that the way to go is to use Poisson Summation Formula (PSF) which I tried. The sum
$\sum_{\boldsymbol{n}=\mathbf{1}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\boldsymbol{n}^{2}+\boldsymbol{b}^{2}}$ is classic and I know how to derive it using PSF. I tried to convolve and derive the CTFT of the term under the sum but with no clear result.

Any suggestions on how to obtain it??

Comment: What do you mean by "obtain"?  Evaluate in closed form?  Evaluate numerically?  For closed form, we can use ${}_2F_1$'s with complex parameters.

Comment: Edited, thanks. I meant that I would like to evaluate it in close form using the hyperbolic functions.

Comment: Simply use the technique [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885441) to obtain $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n\eta)}{n^2+a^2} = \frac{\pi}{a}\frac{\cosh(a(\pi-\eta))}{\sinh (a\pi)} \qquad a\in \mathbb{R}, 0<\eta<2\pi$$

Comment: @pisco's comment then shows that the OP answer is $$\frac{\pi}{2b}\frac{\cosh(b(\pi-\eta))}{\sinh (b\pi)} - \frac{1}{2b^2}$$